# How to prove that the equation $x^2-3y^2=17$ has no integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to prove that the equation $$x^2-3y^2=17$$
has no integer solutions? Can you help me?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275797/show-15x2-7y2-9-has-no-integer-solutions

Comment: @Ayman Hourieh Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x^2-3y^2=17\implies x^2\equiv2\pmod 3$$

but $x$ can be $\equiv 0,\pm1\pmod 3\implies x^2\equiv0,1\pmod 3$

Comment: @bhattachaejee Thank you very much!

Comment: @DaoyiPeng, my pleasure. Don't miss the related question.

Comment: bhattachaejee OK! I need to see some Pell's eqution.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee could you explain to me the step x can be $0, +- 1$? I'm not sure how that proves the answer..

Comment: @user128914, what are the possible remainders when divided by $3$?