# Proving that diophantine equation has no solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am trying to show that the equation $x^5y + 5x^3 - xy^5 = 1$ has no solutions. Anyone has an idea on this?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276904/how-to-prove-that-the-equation-x2-3y2-17-has-no-integer-solutions  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603104/is-7k-9-ever-a-power-of-2 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583126/x3y4-7-has-no-integer-solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^5y+5x^3-xy^5=y(x^5-x)+5x^3-x(y^5-y)$$

Now using [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $\displaystyle a^5-a\equiv0\pmod5$

$\displaystyle\implies$ the left hand side will always be divisible by $5$ for integer $x,y$ unlike the right one.