# Proving that an equation doesn't have integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, congruences

I need to prove that there are no integer solutions for a bunch of equations like the following:
$$15x^2 - 7y^2 = 9$$
I was able to solve some simpler ones by picking a dividend and looking into it's remainder table. But it's not working for the others. How should I start thinking this kind of problem? It's from my algebra class and we are looking into divisibility and congruence. Thanks!

Comment: If it has a solution, then $y$ must be divisible by $3$. Hence also $x$. So dividing by $9$ we get $15m^2-7n^2=1$. But now $n=0\bmod3$ would give $0=1\bmod3$. $n=\pm1\bmod3$ would give $0-1=1\bmod3$. So there are no solutions. There is no guaranteed approach, but that answer combines two things worth trying.

Comment: also look at Diophantine equations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $15x^{2} - 7y^{2} = 9$ has no integer solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275797/show-15x2-7y2-9-has-no-integer-solutions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Maybe note first that $3$ must divide $y$. Let $y=3t$. Then we are looking at $15x^2-(7)(9t^2)=9$. So $3$ must divide $x$. Let $x=3s$. We end up with
$$15s^2-7t^2=1.$$
Now work modulo $3$.

Answer (score 3):

If $15x^2-7y^2=9$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, then $-7y^2\equiv 9\pmod{5}$, i.e. $$3y^2\equiv 9\pmod{5}\stackrel{:3}\iff y^2\equiv 3\pmod{5},$$

contradiction, because $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $5$. To prove this, notice $(5k)^2\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, $(5k\pm 1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $(5k\pm 2)^2\equiv 4\pmod{5}$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

You have modulo $5$ $$-2y^2\equiv 4\pmod 5\iff y^2\equiv -2\pmod 5\iff y^2\equiv 3\pmod 5$$ But the only squares modulo $5$ are $0,1$ and $4$ hence there are not solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Call $x^2=a$ and $y^2=b$ then we have $15a-7b=9$ which is a diaphante equation. It's solution can be found by Euclid's algorithm, but also there is a theorem that no solutions exist iff $9$ isn't a multiple of the $gcd$ of $15$ and $7$.

In this case there are solutions, so you can find them, then show if they can be or can't be 2 squares.

Comment: Do you know how complete this, or are you just guessing that it might  work? How do you propose to show that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be squares? Note that there are *infinitely* many solutions, since if $(a,b)$ is a solution then so too is $(a+7n,b+15n).\ $

Comment: No, that looks to be what you are doing.

Comment: No, I'm simply questioning if your answer is a guess or a real solution.

Comment: And thank you for informing me that there are infinitely many solutions to a linear diaphante equation which has solutions.

Comment: Here there are solutions $(a,b) = \ldots (2.3), (9,18), (16,33),\ldots$ How does your answer prove that $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ are not both squares?

Comment: My answer acknowledges that there are solutions for this case, my answer provides a general test for special cases as to if there are solutions or not for equations of form $Ax^2+By^2=C$ by reducing it to a linear diaphante. You repeating things I've included in my answer many minutes ago, you are simply harassing me. I have no time to deal with people that can't get beyond the internet and how to incorporate it into their lives.

Comment: @marshalcraft: As far as I can see, Bill has done nothing wrong at all here -- he's merely, and correctly, pointing out that your answer is not an answer in that it does not actuallly lead to a solution to the OP's problem. As for "stealing" your non-answer, that does not make sense: Bill has not posted any answer to this question at all (not even a deleted one, which would have been visible to users with 10,000 reputation points).

Comment: Oh interesting the change of opinion on my asnwer, -2 all the sudden. Real mature people. Hey thats fine Ill delete it. That helps everyone right?

Comment: Actually I've decided to keep the answer as it is a partial solution. Your point contest doesn't change mathematical truth unfortunately for you, i guess that one is on my side.